# Pop-up Modal Text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I'm looking for a script that will fire up whenever I click on an input box there will be a pop up modal with TextField and save and cancel button. So when I click save the text i typed on the text field will be saved on the input box.

---

I'm so sorry been busy with something else and I'm so sorry for being not so descriptive with my question (just a newbie). 
 I'm currently using this: 
 mywebdeveloperblog.com/my-jquery-plugins/jquery-popbox 
my only problem is that there's no 'cancel' button so there's no way to cancel in iOS or other touch devices. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you want help, you'll need to be a bit more descriptive with your questions. What have you tried? What technology are you using? PHP, .NET, Classic ASP, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Search for jquery ('#seuID').onclick() function with a alert inside the function it will call and pass the result into a variable or array so you can do what you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function(){
    //your code here
});
```

you can find more info [here](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document)
  .ready(function () {
  $('input')
    .click(    
  function () {
    var NWin = window.open($(this)
      .prop('href'), '', 'height=800,width=800');
    if (window.focus) {
      NWin.focus();
    }
    return false;
  })
});
```